# Split with rules javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to be able to split a string by spaces but not if the spaces are between quotes or parentheses.

```
string = 'My str "hello world" (cool str though)';
```

I want it to output as:

```
['My', 'string', 'hello world', 'cool str though'];
```

Comment: @elclanrs I have no idea how to do it. I was hoping using the split method with a regex parameter.

Comment: You may want to attack this by looking at what you want to keep, rather than what you want to split by.

Comment: @AlexWayne The text is dynamic.. I really wanted a way to do this. But it seems impossible

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible to do with a single regex, but this straddles the line between regex and parser. Some reading: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-beyond-regex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use escapes or nested quotes and parentheses, you can match the sets you define:

```
var rx=/("[^"]+"|\([^(]+\)|[^ ]+)/g,

s='My str "hello world" (cool str though)';

s.match(rx).join('\n')

/*  returned value: (String)
My
str
"hello world"
(cool str though)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a simpler way, but i wrote a small function.

```js
function foo() {
var x = 'My str "hello world" (cool str though)'.split(' ');
 var newx = [];
 for (var i=0,k=0;i<x.length;i++,k++){
  if(x[i].indexOf('"') > -1){
   newx[k] = x[i];
   i++;
   while( i<x.length ){
    newx[k] = newx[k] + ' ' + x[i];
    if(x[i].indexOf('"') > -1)break;
    i++;
   }
   continue;
  }
  else if(x[i].indexOf('(') > -1){
   newx[k] = x[i];
   i++;
   while( i<x.length ){
    newx[k] = newx[k] + ' ' + x[i];
    if(x[i].indexOf(')') > -1)break;
    i++;
   }
   continue;
  }
  else newx[k]=x[i];
 }
 alert(newx);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="foo()">bar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be not very fancy, but it does the job. I haven't tested it on large sets, but it works for your example.

```js
var strng = 'My str "hello world" (cool str though)';

function split(str, ignore1, ignore2) {
    var result = new Array();
    var pos = 0;
    var blocked = false;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        console.log("pos: " + pos + ", i:" + i);
        if (blocked) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == blocked) {
               result.push(str.substr(pos, i - pos));
                pos = i + 1;
                blocked = false;
            }
        } else {
            var ignPos = ignore1.indexOf(str.charAt(i));
            if ( ignPos > -1 ){
              console.log('blocked: '+str.charAt(i));
              blocked=ignore2[ignPos];
              pos = i + 1;
            } else if (str.charAt(i) == " ") {
                console.log('found');
                if (i==pos+1 || i==pos) {
                    pos = pos + 1;
                } else {
                    result.push(str.substr(pos, i - pos));
                    pos = i + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  if (pos!=str.length){result.push(str.substr(pos, i - pos))};
    return result;
}

console.log(split(strng, ['"','('], ['"',')']));
```